# How select an aggregated row in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with aggregated columns like this in a SQL Server. The goal is: Show me any row that contains Street A or B.

| Name | Adresses |
| --- | --- |
| Mike | Street A, Street B, Street C |
| Smith | Street B |
| Jimmy | Street C |

```
Declare @street table (col nvarchar (50) )
INSERT INTO @street Values ('Street A'), ('Street B' )

SELECT *
FROM Table 
WHERE Adresses like '%' + @street + '%'

SELECT *
FROM Table 
WHERE Adresses = ( SELECT * FROM  @street )

SELECT *
FROM Table 
WHERE STRING_SPLIT(Adresses,',') in ( SELECT * FROM  @street )
```

It does not work. I do not get results. The results should be like this:

| Name | Adresses |
| --- | --- |
| Mike | Street A, Street B, Street C |
| Smith | Street B |

Comment: Why are you storing delimited data in the first place? Normalise your design. Also `Declare @street nvarchar table (col nvarchar (50) )` isn't valid syntax.

Comment: Your real issue is why are you storing *multiple* addresses in a single column. fix your design and the issue no longer exits.

Comment: I mean or. Street A or B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get rid of this bad structure and store the data in a better form in future.

Anyway, following your intention to use `STRING_SPLIT` for that, this would do:

```
SELECT name, adresses  
FROM yourtable  
WHERE EXISTS 
  (SELECT *  
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(adresses, ',')  
    WHERE value IN ('Street A', 'Street B'));
```

You should read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#d-search-by-tag-value), that's explained there.

Testing with your sample data succeeds: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GhgUHeMK)

Comment: This seems to work. This is great. Its like a LIKE IN = EXISTS with STRING_SPLIT method.

Comment: Its better to use this one: ( SELECT value 
             FROM STRING_SPLIT( (REPLACE(adresses,' ','')) , ',')

Comment: @PeterXO If you go and use such a "complicated" solution, you might reach the point where you would do better just using simple "LIKE" two times ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you can use some "contains" functionality on column adresses. Depends if the column is a varchar/text like column, or a array like column.

However, i would instead try to solve this in a more conseptual level.

In relational databases, this would be referred as a "many to one" relationship.
One adress may have only one Persons related to them, while the Person may have listed many Adresses.
Therefore i would make seperate tables. Then you can easily Search the Adresses table for A and B and find related foreign keys to Persons table.

Otherwise, you can insist on using "contains" functionality, but this might get computationally expensive.

Comment: Answer needs some code examples.